# How to trigger a calculation when any datagridview cell gets updated

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've created this calculation to be triggered when a button is clicked, it will multiply 2 datagridview columns and show the result in a third, and then sums the total of 2 columns and send result into 2 text boxes

now I want to make this happen whenever a value is entered to the datagridview or edited (one of the columns is product quantity) so when entered it should redo the calculations... so which void should I add this code to?

```
private void btnClearPN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        decimal a = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
        decimal b = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);

        decimal c = a * b;

        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = c.ToString();


    }
    GrandTotal();
    Qty();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Option - Update Cell Values when the user has finished editing**

You should handle the `CellEndEdit` event of the DataGridView if you want to update the DataGridView when the user has finished editing values (this is determined by the user moving to the next Cell or moving to another control on your form). Refer to [MSDN - DataGridView.CellEndEdit Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit(v=vs.110).aspx) for further information.

> Occurs when edit mode stops for the currently selected cell.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs dataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            decimal b = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);

            decimal c = a * b;

            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = c.ToString();
        }

        GrandTotal();
        Qty();
    }
```

**Second Option - Update Cell Values as the user is typing**

Using this method is a bit more involved and requires correctly handling the `EditControlShowing` event and, for a `TextBox` it's `TextChanged` event.

You should handle the `EditControlShowing` event of the DataGridView if you want to update the DataGridView as the user is typing. This event will give you access to the Edit Control. For simple DataGridView setups this is a TextBox. Though this could easily be a ComboBox, CheckBox or any number of other controls.

Refer to [MSDN - DataGridView.EditingControlShowing Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing(v=vs.110).aspx) for further information.

> Occurs when a control for editing a cell is showing..

```
    private DataGridViewRow CurrentRow;
    private void DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs dataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs)
    {
        CurrentRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
        TextBox textBox = dataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs.Control as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            textBox.TextChanged -= textBox_TextChanged;
            textBox.TextChanged += textBox_TextChanged;
        }
    }

    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal(CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
        decimal b = Convert.ToDecimal(CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value);

        decimal c = a * b;

        CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value = c.ToString();
    }
```

**Note:** It is essential that you include the line:

```
textBox.TextChanged -= textBox_TextChanged;
```

As the handlers are added at runtime, each time the Edit Control is shown, it is necessary to remove any previously added handler otherwise it will be called multiple times.

Comment: Tried that, Jay.. Still no luck.. should I attach the full code?

Comment: Describe how it doesn't work, and note that I changed your original `Convert.ToInt32` to `Convert.ToDecimal`

Comment: I have noticed, but it will not change the values except if I click on the button or clicked on the third column's cells, but will not change after editing the quantity

Comment: @JoeyArnanzo If I understand you correctly, the totals get updated when you move away from the DataGridView or move to the next cell? You would like to update the totals as the user enters/changes the values?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Thank you

Comment: @JoeyArnanzo take a look at the Second Option I added. I think I added everything you need to know